# URL amigável em codeigniter com ênfase em SEO

Tags: php, codeigniter

Amigos, estou desenvolvendo um blog em CI. E pensando no SEO do blog, gostaria que a URL ao invés de ser apresentada desta forma:

> https://meusite.com.br/blog/postagem/1

Gostaria que fosse exibido com o título do post.

> https://meusite.com.br/blog/titulo-do-meu-post

Minha Route está assim:

```
$route['blog/(:num)'] = "blog/postagem/$1";
```

Meu controller está assim (não se preocupem com a gambiarra, assim que eu solucionar essa questão de SEO eu crio os Models corretamente):

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function postagem($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $data['blog'] = $this->db->get('blog')->result();
        $this->load->view('site/blog/postagem', $data);
    }
    public function home(){
        $data['blog'] = $this->db->get('blog')-> result();
        $this->load->view('site/blog/home' , $data);
    }
```

View postagem:

```
<?php foreach ($blog as $post ) { ?>
    <h1><?php echo $post->titulo; ?>- <small><?php echo $post->categoria;?></small></h1>
    <p><?php echo $post->texto;?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php } ?>
```

View Home:

```
<?php foreach ($blog as $post ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('blog/postagem');?>/<?php echo $post->titulo; ?>"><?php echo $post->titulo?></a>
    <hr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Gostaria de saber como realmente o CI vai identificar que o titulo na url corresponde a um ID na Route.. não consigo entender, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que um dos requisitos pra você encontrar a sua resposta, é compreender como o **CodeIgniter** interpreta as *URLs*.

A representação seria dessa forma:

`dominio.com.br / classe / método / IDs e outros parâmetros`

Portanto, quando você acessa: https://meusite.com.br/blog/postagem/1, a classe do *Controller* `Blog` é carregada e o método `postagem` é executado, recebendo o parâmetro `1` via *GET*.

No código é exatamente o que você já tem:

```
<?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function postagem($id)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Agora, quando você utiliza rotas, você está "mascarando" isso. Internamente tudo funciona da mesma forma, porém a *URI* é tratada de maneira diferente, ou seja, o **CodeIgniter** efetua o remapeamento antes da execução.

Se você deseja transformar a sua *URL* em algo assim:
https://meusite.com.br/blog/titulo-do-meu-post, terá que configurar a rota da seguinte maneira:

```
$route['blog/(.+)'] = 'blog/postagem/$1';
```

E então receber no método `postagem` o parâmetro que será o título do *post* podendo seguir a forma como o @Phelipe sugeriu.

**Fontes:**

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#uri-segments

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#uri-routing

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [url_title()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=url_title#url_title). A função pega uma string como entrada e cria uma string de URL amigável. Você pega o título da sua postagem e passar por essa função e usa como parte da URL. Você guarda essa parte da url no seu banco de dados e ao ao pesquisar no seu banco de dados por uma notícia, você não faz pelo `ID`, e sim pro essa parte da url.

Sugiro ler um exemplo que a própria documentação do Codeigniter trás de como implementar um site de notícias. Você pode encontrar esse exemplo [aqui](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Show ! isso já vai me ajudar.. não pensei que teria algo do tipo lá! durante esse meio tempo achei em um fórum americano a seguinte solução: <a href="<?php echo site_url().'blog/postagem/'.$post->id.'/'.implode('-',explode(' ',preg_replace('/[^ \w]+/','', $post->titulo))) ?> "><?php echo $post->titulo?></a>